# How to convert a mention tag text to a <router-link> ? (VUEJS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a body property in data

```
data(){
 return{
  body:'Hello im @username1 and @username2'
 }
}
```

I want to convert each @user into a code below, where a user can click that link to go that url path.

```
<router-link :to="`/${username1}`">@{{username1}}</router-link>
```

**What i tried**

```
<span v-html='bodyReplaced'>
  computed: {
    bodyReplaced(){
      return this.body.replace(
        /@\w+/g, 
        (user) => '<router-link :to="`/${username1}`">@{{username1}}</router-link>'
      )
    }
  }
```

What the code did:

1. Convert the string into router-link in the dom but not in the view
2. I dont know how to replace the @ after the match, so i can use it in to="`/${username1}

Comment: let suppose that you could replace the mentioned users by the router-link component but you this will not work because the component (router link) could not be parsed

Comment: Don't try to mess with strings. Write function in the template that renders a list of actual components, either with plain strings or with router-links.

Comment: i understand, how can this work? any example? @Bergi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a component called `mention` and pass the user name as prop, i used the same approach of @Bergi, or you could replaced a computed property in which you replace the mention uder by `a` element which could be parsed not like router-link :

```js
Vue.component('mention', {
  template: `<router-link :to="'/'+user">@{{user}}</router-link>`,
  props: ['user']
})
const Foo = {
  template: '<div>im foo</div>'
}
const Bar = {
  template: '<div>im bar</div>'
}
const routes = [{
    path: '/foo',
    component: Foo
  },
  {
    path: '/bar',
    component: Bar
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes, // short for `routes: routes`,

})

// 4. Create and mount the root instance.
// Make sure to inject the router with the router option to make the
// whole app router-aware.
const app = new Vue({
  router,
  data() {
    return {
      body: 'Hello im @foo and @bar'
    }
  },

  computed: {
    tokens() {
      return this.body.split(' ');
    },
    bodyReplaced() {
      return this.body.split(' ').map(w => {
        return w.startsWith('@') ? `<a href="#/${w.slice(1)}">${w}</a>` : w;
      }).join(' ')
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>********The first solution********</div>

  <template v-for="token in tokens">
    
     <mention v-if="token.startsWith('@')" :user="token.slice(1)"></mention>
     <template v-else>&nbsp;{{token}}&nbsp;</template>
  </template>
  <div>********The second solution********</div>
  <span v-html='bodyReplaced'></span>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Comment: ok let me try it and back to you, are you this is the only way to do it? i think its too verbose for this action, or your think its ok?

Comment: please check the second solution i think its close to your approach

Comment: i want something like the second solution, this have to be simple like your second approach, the problem here is, its a a tag, its possible to make the second approach using router-link?

Comment: how good practice will be use a tag to router to profile user instead of using router link?

Comment: as mentioned in official [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) : *Note that you cannot use v-html to compose template partials, because Vue is not a string-based templating engine. Instead, components are preferred as the fundamental unit for UI reuse and composition* so the router-link is vue component not a html element, it will not parsed, it will be shown as raw html

Comment: of course, thats the problem, please use that note in paste in your answer, and please change it to the second approach, most people will like to use this simple way. Remember that the a href property has to be /profile/username without @ Thanks!

Comment: i used to `w.slice(1)` to remove the `@` sign, i think keeping the two solutions is better since some people like to style their tags in some way and this is more easy when using a dedicated component

Comment: of course, and its easy, ust add a class to the a tag and got to go, thanks for the support.  I think theres not performance issue using a tag for that instead of router-link, they will do the same

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for something like

```
<template v-for="part of body.split(/(@\w+)/g)">
  <router-link v-if="part[0] == '@'" :to="`/${part.slice(1)}`">{{part}}</router-link>
  <template v-else>{{part}}</template>
</template>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: 'main',
  data: {
    body:'Hello im @username1 and @username2'
  },
  router: new VueRouter({
    routes: []
  }),
})
```

```html
<main>
  <template v-for="part of body.split(/(@\w+)/g)">
    <router-link v-if="part[0] == '@'" :to="`/${part.slice(1)}`">{{part}}</router-link>
    <template v-else>{{part}}</template>
  </template>
</main>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, im using your code and i got this console error Property or method "part" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render @Bergi

Comment: It probably needs to be `v-for`

Comment: @AlexHunter Like NickG said, I misspelled `v-for` as `for`. Added complete example.

Comment: i saw that too and use v-for, but using v-for and now got this error Custom elements in iteration require 'v-bind:key' directives @Bergi

Comment: @AlexHunter Is that an actual error or just a linter complaint? The above snippet works. I guess a `key` is not really necessary for lists that short. If you really want, [you can use the index as a key](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/v-for-with-simple-arrays-what-key-to-use/13692/3) though.

Comment: the linter, let me try it and back to you @Bergi